# Is the 'zope' package widely used?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, interface, zope.interface

I want to implement my project using interface oriented programming. Since Python itself does not have native support to the Interface keyword, I am planning to leverage the `zope.*` package. But the `zope.component` package is really a huge package with lots of dependencies. Because I want to keep my project slim with less external dependency, I am wonder if it is useful/helpful to use the `zope.*` packages. Especially I am planning to deploy my project in GAE, and it does not include the `zope` package as a supported third-party package.

If not using `zope.*` package, what is the best practice to implement Python project with interface oriented concepts?

Comment: What would you need explicit interfaces for when the whole language is duck-typed? For that matter, what are those "interface oriented principles" you speak of?

Comment: bare my language, I was meaning 'interface oriented programming'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`zope.interface`](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/). For example, it is used by Twisted, Pyramid frameworks.